# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' printing css error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to print text of a job for.  Unfortunately, the href keeps displaying none and I keep getting errors for printing the text I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/Bookmaker improved ALTERNATIVE.py", 
line 155, in <module>
    print(bet.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Code below or full code [here](http://textuploader.com/d4eja)

```
with open('Aperture Science.csv', 'a+', newline='\n') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for section in sections:
            try:
                link = section.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 a").get_attribute("href")
                print((section.get_attribute('href')))
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            time.sleep(7)
            try:
                team_name = section.find_element_by_css_selector(".row:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").text
                print(section.text)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            time.sleep(7)
            try:
                bet = section.find_element_by_css_selector(".odds .odds span").text
                print(bet.text)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            time.sleep(7)
            writer.writerow((bet, team_name, link))
```

I have tried variations like:

```
for section in sections:
    try:
        link = section.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 a").get_attribute("href")
        print((link.get_attribute('href')))
```

As well as:

```
team_name = section.find_element_by_css_selector(".row:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").text
print(team_name.text)
```

`print(section.text)` works, though this is not the text I am wanting to print.  Any ideas?

Comment: please post the entire trace back for the error

Comment: @0TTT0 http://textuploader.com/d4ej7

Comment: You assign `bet = section.find...(....).text` and then expect `bet.text` to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bet = section.find_element_by_css_selector(".odds .odds span").text` already returned you a text value of the first node.

If you want to print a list of text values, then you need to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` as below:

```
links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in section.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3 a")]
team_names = [team_name.text for team_name in section.find_elements_by_css_selector(".row:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)")]
bets = [bet.text for bet in section.find_elements_by_css_selector(".odds .odds span")]
writer.writerow(bets, team_names, links)
```

Comment: Thanks!   Works alright in console though the csv doesn't look right https://ibb.co/hm2YMR

Comment: How exactly output should looks like? Remove empty strings?

Comment: Try `writer.writerow(bets[0], team_names[0], links[0])`

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to like that either.  I've posted my full code and error here https://pastebin.com/fKtkNCG5

Comment: `writer.writerow((bets[0], team_names[0], links[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

if team_name is sth's text, then print(team_name) is enough.

Comment: Nearly. It only prints one text for me where as I need a list